# Codeigniter basepath system

Tags: php, codeigniter

In my view folder I putt one template and all its files but that template didn't load its css through codeigniter . Later I echo the basepath:

```
echo basepath;
```

This gives me this path:

`/var/www/xxx/CI/system/`

Doesn't it show the default path to that particular folder where the file is. My assumption is that it should give this path:

`/var/www/xxx/CI/application/views`

Thanks

Comment: What does this have to do with CSS? For CSS you will want to use the URL not the local path.

Comment: css are in the same folder too . like this
/var/www/xxx/CI/application/views/css/

Comment: i just cant able to understand that why its showing me that path 
/var/www/xxx/CI/system/ 
please correct me if i am wrong by default it has to show me this path
/var/www/xxx/CI/application/views
Right ?

Comment: Yeah, but for people to be able to access your CSS  you need the **URL**, not the local path.

Comment: in my html file i am including the css like this 
    <link href="css/index.css" rel="stylesheet" /> , so there should not be problem as when i access the html file with CI , it shows me page with css loaded but when i access the page through CI css is not loaded

Comment: So what does `BASEPATH` have to do with CSS? To asnwer your question: yes it is correct that is returns the path of your app's system folder.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/27272/discussion-between-user1224233-and-mischa)

Comment: @user1224233 If an answer helped you, please mark it as correct.

Comment: it's important to note that `BASEPATH` the constant, is different from `base_url()` the function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should place your `css` and other public assets in a folder in the site root.

For example:

```
/webapp
  /application
  /public
    /css
      /main.css
    /js
      /plugins.js
    /img
      /narwhals.png
  /system
  /index.php
  /license.txt
```

Then, from inside your view, you can use:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="<?php echo site_url('public/css/main.css'); ?>">
```

Also, in `application/config/config.php` you change the `base_url` like this:

```
$config['base_url'] = '';
```

It should be on line 17 of that file.

Comment: i tried that and site_url gives me path with index.php file which i couldnt able to fix yet .

Comment: Have a look at [`Removing the index.php file`](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/urls.html) in the docs. Or if you've defined it correct in the config use `base_url()`.

Answer (score 0):

the reason it gives the base path is you may want to access files in another directory (such as css or save uploaded images). To get the views subdirectory, you just use:

```
APPPATH. '/views';
```

note that if you are inside a view, you can get the basepath with:

```
 dirname(__FILE__)
```

in one step.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't place your css files inside your views folder. Usually only your webserver should have direct access to that folder.

You can use [`base_url()`](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/helpers/url_helper.html). Used it a thousand times for that purpose.

Answer (score 0):

In order to include css with dynamic folder path do this

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url();?>YOUR_STYLEFILE.css" >
```

Answer (score 0):

```
echo FCPATH;
```

use defined variable

Answer (score -1):

```
$this->load->helper('url'); 

echo base_url();
```